# What's the meaning of "RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=45]" in Ionic's ISAPI Rewriting Filter Rules?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite, iirf

I found this rule in my INI file of the IIRF Isapi Filter (to rewrite urls on the server), anyone can help me to understand what's mean? I found that "S=45" it's only to jump lines, but what is the meaning of "-"?

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=45]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[S=x]` modifier tells [`mod_rewrite` to skip the next x rules for the matching urls.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_s) Since the instruction is to skip the rules, the `-` is just a placeholder, the url is not really rewritten.

By the way, [`IIRF` does not support the `[S]` modifier](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/a8988008-feb2-4a91-9abc-03043ba308fe.htm), this line may comes from an incorrectly adapted `mod_rewrite` configuration.